# C# Syntax Highlighting broken?

Tags: bug, status-declined, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

[In my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543916/setting-sharpdx-windows-renderform-isfullscreen-before-renderloop-run-corrupts-w), the C# highlighting is incorrect:

- Randomly, the `DXGI` namespace isn't highlighted (maybe because all uppercase)
- `bool` and `get` are not recognized as keywords.
- `set` is recognized as a type name.

And I wonder why!

- The question has a [C#] tag.
- I even directed the highlighter that the big code block consists of C# code with `<!-- language: lang-cs -->`

What did I do wrong? :(

Comment: You did nothing wrong. It's working as intended. For more information, see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the DXGI namespace isn't highlighted (maybe because all uppercase).

That's pretty much it. The prettifier is very simple and basic; it [highlights words in CamelCase as types](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js#594), but `DXGI` is not using camel-case.

Issues with the prettifier should be reported to the [Google Code Prettify project](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). However, I'd wager this specific issue is already known.